# How To Replace All Matching Array Elements?

Tags: arrays, swift

I am replacing an item in my array with this code:

```
var array = ["", "Orange", "Grape", "Apple"]
if let i = array.firstIndex(of: "") {
                            array[i] = "Blank"
                        }
                        print("\(array)"). //["Blank", "Orange", "Grape", "Apple"]
```

My only issue with this is it only replaces the FIRST item matching, so my question is-- is there any way to replace ALL items matching?

It's possible this has been answered before but I'm unable to find it.

Comment: ```array = array.map{$0.isEmpty ? "Blank" : $0}``` this one maybe helpfull

Comment: This seems to have worked, thankyou much Raja

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can iterate your array with a map and replace empty strings with data.

```
array = array.map{$0.isEmpty ? "Blank" : $0}
```